# How to create an string array with defined element in one instruction?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

How to create an string array with defined element ? for example i would like to do:

```
var myArray : Tarray<string>;
.....
myArray := ['aaa','bbb'];
```

something like this, init the array in one row

Comment: Actually, your code works in Delphi XE7 (IIRC) and later.

Comment: but not under xe2 :(

Comment: The question is tagged *delphi* and so is a generic Delphi question, for any version.  If you wanted to ask about XE2 you need to add the *delphi-xe2* tag.

Comment: @David: yes, but if something only works in XE7 and later, it is not a generic solution either.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, if any question is tagged with Delphi only without specifying the version, I take for granted that an answer valid for the current Delphi version is acceptable.

Comment: Indeed. If there is no version tag it's fine to answer targeting the latest version. By generic I'm implying not specific to any particular version. As the question isn't.

Comment: @David: so not specific to XE7+, nor specific to the latest version.

Comment: In my opinion, if there is no version tag you are free to answer targeting any version you please, but there should be a presumption that you target modern versions.

Answer (score 5):

Besides that your code actually works for XE7 and up (as Andreas already mentioned), you can use `Create` to initialize a generic array:

```
  myArray := TArray<string>.Create('aaa','bbb');
```

Since Delphi 10.3 Rio you can even combine the declaration with that assignment in case `myArray` happens to be a local variable:

```
  var myArray := TArray<string>.Create('aaa','bbb');
```

Answer (score 4):

In Delphi 10.3 Rio, it is possible to declare variables [inline](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Inline_Variable_Declaration) in code:

```
begin
  ...
  var myArray : TArray<String> := ['aaa','bbb'];
  ...
end;
```

The type could even be [inferred](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Inline_Variable_Declaration#Type_Inference_for_Inlined_Variables) :

```
begin
  ...
  var myArray := ['aaa','bbb'];
  ...
end;
```

---

As others have mentioned, your code works from Delphi XE7.

It also allows to declare a dynamic array in both these ways:

```
var
  myArray : TArray<String> = ['aaa','bbb'];  // Only works for global variables
const
  myArray : TArray<String> = ['aaa','bbb'];
```

Comment: FWIW, the `var name: type = ...` only compiles for **global** variables, not for local ones. 10.3 Rio has inline declared variables, but they are slightly different again. In the var *section* of a function, `var name: type = ...` still doesn't compile.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, I don't understand your last sentence. It seems to repeat the first sentence, but with a mixup with inlined variables, which is irrelevant.

Comment: Well, inline variables are local variables too, and there you can do `var name: type := ...`, but not in the *var section*, i.e. *before the begin of the function block*. There it still won't compile, not even with the new inline variables in place. We discussed this with Embarcadero R&D, but for now, it was not decided.

Answer (score -3):

You can do it via [assignable typed constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Declared_Constants#Typed_Constants):

```
const
  myArray: array [0..1] of string = ('aaa','bbb');
```

Make sure this option is turned on in the project properties (on `Compiling` tab).

Comment: Assignable typed constants are bad, and this question is a bout dynamic arrays.

Comment: @David: Well, nothing in the code above shows they are assignable. What is important is that they are typed constants. They should not be assignable, but that is a compile directive not shown here. Anyway, you are right: this is about dynarrays.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I assumed the answer referred to [writeable typed constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Declared_Constants#Writeable_Typed_Constants) but perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: @David: so did I, but nothing in the code above makes them writeable per se, nor does the link talk about assignable or writeable constants. Just about typed constants. I have no idea why Miamy thinks they should be *assignable*, or why he calls them assignable.

Comment: @Rudy "nor does the link talk about assignable or writeable constants". It does if you scroll down.

Comment: @Rudy, David: "Assignable typed constants" is how it calls at project options tab in IDE (least XE3).

Comment: @Miamy: That project option makes normal typed constants assignable. It is off by default and the construct is simply called "typed constant". In the early days, it was actually on by default (or actually, there was not even a directive for it), but as soon as they realized that writeable constants were not a good thing, they changed that (in the D6 or D7 timeframe, IIRC).